# How can i just read from database for android

Tags: android, sqlite

I try to write a program for dormitory's refectory. I take infos from dormitory's director and data will be probably as excel. I can convert this csv, db or something like that.

But for example if i make a table what has 30 columns, should i write these in the code one by one or can i do that automatically. Because i research on the internet and i always see they create database and after read it in the code.

For example

```
 public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
  String sql = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_COUNTRIES + "(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,country_name TEXT,country_code TEXT" + ")";
```

in this code, id country_name and country_code had written with hand. If we have more columns how can i do that with easily.

Comment: you could give http://ormlite.com/ or http://greendao-orm.com/ a shot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can easily create the query string with dynamic column name. ex

```
public String createQuery(String tablename,int colcount){
    String query = "CREATE TABLE "
            + tablename + "(" ;

    for(int i=0;i<colcount;i++){

        if(i==colcount-1){
            query+= "COL"+i+" TEXT );";
        }else{
            query+= "COL"+i+" TEXT,";
        }


    }

    return query;
}
```

now you can execte the query by db.execSQL(createQuery("PRODUCT", 10));

Answer (score 0):

You can name your columns like `col1`,`col2`.. etc.. for this u can generate the sql using

```
String sql = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_COUNTRIES + "(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,country_name TEXT,country_code TEXT";

//change the **limit** as per ur needs
for(int i=1;i<=10;i++){
   //change the datatype from text to ur desired data type
   sql += ", col" + String.valueOf(i) + " text ";
}
sql += ")";
```

Comment: You write id,countr_name and country_code after "TABLE_COUNTRIES". If i have for example 30 columns should i write one by one.

Comment: try naming the columns as col1, col2 and generate it via the looping statement or use any ORM to generate it automatically or else you have to write manually :-/